# Display only the latest post

Tags: categories, taxonomy, php

There seems to be something wrong with the logic of what I'm doing.

I just want to display the latest post in a custom term. But instead I'm displaying every post for that term, even though I am using `posts_per_page => 1`

I have a taxonomy called "twin" and the term "double portrait", I have 2 posts in a category called "celebrity", both with the term "double portrait". The code I have outputs in the right category fine, but as I say it's outputting for each post instead of just the one.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
 $post_type = 'post';

  $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );

  foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) : 

    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

  foreach( $terms as $term ) : 

    $args = array(
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $term->slug
          )
        ),
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, 
      'orderby' => 'modified',
      );

  $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

  if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
  if(in_category($str)) {
    if(has_term('double portrait','twin')) {
        echo the_excerpt();
    }

  }

  endwhile; endif;

  endforeach;

  endforeach;
```

Comment: In which template are you using this?

Comment: What is this `posts $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );`? That must be a typo?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes it was a type I had copied over a comment from the code by accident. This is a template part for the index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query arguments, formatted to be readable, look like this:

```
$args = array(
  'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 
  'term' => $term->slug, 
  'posts_per_page' => 1, 
  'orderby' => 'modified',
  'category' => $str 
);
```

That does not match any argument pattern I see for [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). I think you are trying to construct a `tax_query` but that should look like this:

```
$args = array(
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $term->slug
    )
  ),
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, 
  'orderby' => 'modified',
  'category' => $str 
);
```

I am not sure why you have a `tax_query` *and* a `category` argument. Perhaps that is a mistake, perhaps you want an `AND` or `OR` relationship between the taxonomies. I am not sure.

I suspect that you also want `ignore_sticky_posts` so I added that.

Comment: I have a category argument because I want to display posts in the main category of say something like dance, but also with the term landscape or double portrait that I created with a taxonomy. I didn't know about tax_query, thanks, that's cleaned up my argument a lot. I'm still getting more than one post for my query though :/

Comment: This kind of question is hard to test since I don't have your data in my database. You can roll that category argument into the `tax_query` though, and I would if were you.

Comment: Your tax_query worked perfectly.